# How to get specific field from list using linq? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call from my model which is a list to view using linq. How can i get the specific field in the list? I wanted to get the value from the list
Here's the model

Model.cs

```
public class Grouping
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I would call it to the ViewModel like this

```
public List<Grouping> LeistungartGroup { get; set; }
```

and here's how im trying to get it to the view.

```
@foreach (var LA in Model.Select(a => a.LeistungartGroup).Distinct())
{
    //enter code here
    //How to get LA.Value here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This for loop  should work

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.LeistungartGroup.Count; i++)
    {    

        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.LeistungartGroup[i].Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.LeistungartGroup[i].Value)
        
     }
```